# Webassembly games and low latency keyboard mouse

Tags: javascript, interrupt-handling, webassembly

How to implement low latency keyboard/mouse input for Wasm application?
How did the angery bots implemented it?
http://webassembly.org/demo/

is there a way to send interupts inside a wasm app?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a browser embedding currently, you can only call into and out of WebAssembly through JavaScript. The easiest is to rely on Emscripten to expose such APIs, for example with [SDL2](https://github.com/emscripten-ports/SDL2) (which supports mouse events) or [html5.h](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/html5.h.html). Unity (used for the AngryBots demo) has its own [mouse handling](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html). You could avoid Emscripten and roll your own, but depending on what you do it may get complicated.

WebAssembly can be called from JavaScript, so its regular [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) is the fastest interrupt rate you can get. Emscripten and Unity expose their own version of this event loop, and have callbacks for the mouse events.

Later on, WebAssembly may [gain APIs](http://webassembly.org/docs/gc/) that give it direct access to the DOM and other browser APIs.